# Send Email With Python smtplib [Errno 11003] getaddrinfo failed Error

Tags: python, smtplib

I want to send email with smtplib and no app password. But i get this output:

> with smtplib.SMTP("blabla@outlook.com",587) as prt:
> socket.gaierror: [Errno 11003] getaddrinfo failed

My wrong code:

```
import smtplib
with smtplib.SMTP("blabla@outlook.com",587) as prt:
    prt.starttls()
    prt.login(user="blabla@outlook.com",password="password")
    prt.sendmail(from_addr="blabla@outlook.com",to_addrs="albalb@outlook.com",msg="Subject:Tester\n\nHello")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mentioned error occurs because of incorrect information in the code causes failure while trying to connect to the SMTP server. Also you have to provide the domain service. Here in your code it is outlook.com, so 'smtp-mail.outlook.com'.

I have imported the EmailMessage for better formatting of the code, and that is way better way to understand. Also we are using port 465 for SSL connection. You can also add multiple recipients inside the contacts list separated by a comma.

```
import os
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage

#credentials
email_user = YOUR EMAIL ID HERE
email_pass = YOUR PASSWORD HERE

contacts = ['ENTER RECIPIENTS HERE']
sender = email_user
to = contacts

msg = EmailMessage()
msg['Subject'] = 'YOUR EMAIL SUBJECT HERE'
msg['From'] = sender
msg['To'] = ', '.join(contacts)
msg.set_content('YOUR EMAIL MESSAGE HERE')

with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp-mail.outlook.com', 465) as smtp:
    smtp.login(email_user, email_pass)
    smtp.send_message(msg)
```

Comment: so what you mean is you need to use "smtp-mail.outlook.com" to do it without using app password. I guess this is our host and it's password 465?  And what does email_pass? My outlook password or third party app password? If it is third party app password, i dont have access to it.

Comment: Can you please tell me what exactly you mean by app password? email_pass in my code is the password of your email id, which is required for authentication because smtplib sends email using the simple mail transfer protocol which requires authentication with proper email id and password. 465 is just a port number.

Comment: Thank you very much, I succeeded after a lot of effort.